# Python/SQL query to use ROWID to realign out of sync data in SQLite3 db

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I have an SQLite3 table with 4 columns, "date", "price", "price2" and "vol".There are about 200k lines of data, but the last 2 columns are out of sync by 798 rows. That is the values of the second two columns in row 1, actually correspond to the values of the first two columns at row 798.

I am using Python 2.7.

I was thinking there must be a way of using the ROWID column as a unique identifier where i can extract the first two columns, then extract the second two columns and rejoin based upon "ROWID+798" or something like that.

Is this possible and if so would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: So you're database is completely corrupt, but you think you can still salvage it? I admire your confidence.

Comment: Haha I'll be honest with you, I am pretty much a complete novice at this stuff so I am most likely approaching things from the wrong angle. I know what I actually want to do is way beyond me, so I am having to fudge things left right and center. I actually inputed the data this way, knowing I would have to move the two columns by that amount of rows. I cound't delete them in csv format as the file was too large to do in excel, and a txt file doesn't let one select just columns, it selects rows as well - so i couldn't delete them manually.

Comment: Show some example records, and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious how your database could get corrupt like that, and sceptical about your assessment that you seem to know exactly what is wrong. If something like this could happen it seems likely that there are many other problems.

In any case, the query you describe should be like this, if i understood correctly.

In most DBMS's you could do this with one subquery, but the syntax `(col1,col2) =` is not allowed in SQLite, so you have to do it like this.

```
UPDATE table1 t SET
        col1 =
        (SELECT col1 FROM table1
        WHERE t.rowid = rowid - 798),
        col2 =
        (SELECT col2 FROM table1
        WHERE t.rowid = rowid - 798)
```

Comment: Many thanks - I shall have a play around with this! I appreciate your help

Comment: I'll take your word for it.